# Adding a user control after a postback within an UpdatePanel, followed by another postback - how to get the input of controls within the user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, viewstate

I have a user control which is being loaded to the page dynamically after performing a postback within an UpdatePanel.

Then I'm performing another postback for saving, where I would like to access the user input for the controls within that user control (for example, a grid with a checkbox in every row).

A simplified example if this scenario would be something as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div><asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add User Control" OnClick="ButtonAdd_OnClick" /></div>
        <div id="divContent" runat="server"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div><asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonSave_OnClick" /></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl uc = Page.LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx") as MyUserControl;
    divContent.Controls.Add(uc);
}

protected void ButtonSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hopefully, get controls from within the user control's grid and save their input
}
```

The problem is that after the save button is clicked, the user control is gone. That's understandable and I have no problem creating and adding it again - but I do want to access the user input and save it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add controls `programatically` then choose `Page_Load` (more preferred) or Page_Init event. You can solve your problem by adding control "statically" (`design time`) with `visible=fals`e and later you may turn on its visibility.

In case you want stick with current approach as in your post, you have to use a *trick*.

```
MyUserControl uc;

protected void Page_Load()
{
   if(ViewState["isAdd"]!=null)
    {
       AddControl();
    }
}

void AddControl()
{
    uc = Page.LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx") as MyUserControl;
    divContent.Controls.Add(uc);
}

protected void ButtonAdd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ViewState["isAdd"]==null)
        AddControl();
    ViewState["isAdd"]="yes";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the internal controls, you have to expose them with properties or use `FindControl`.

Also, as you mentioned, you have add dynamic controls back to the page on each postback.

[Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Comment: I mentioned that I understand it needs to be added again. But my problem is the need to access the user input of controls within the user control.